# Anyway to fix the Graphics shattering problem?

Tags: graphic-drivers, graphics

I'm having issues with the graphics not a big problem though but it needs to be fixed youtu.be/fMPKw5EkOew this video is posted on youtube by another user but this is what I got and it didn't happen always but I have it and I'm worry about I hope someone can help me to fix it.
Thank you.